# How to disable editing and inline-editing for a single record in SuiteCRM/SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm wondering what the best way to disable editing and inline-editing for a single record in SuiteCRM/SugarCRM. I am familiar with how to remove the edit button from the dropdown menu when looking at a detail view record (although it still allows the inline-edit capability).

I am also familiar with `$dependencies` and making a specific field disabled under certain conditions. But I am looking for something that allows me to programatically type in an ID of a record within a specific module, and automatically no user would be able to edit that record (no access to edit view, and no inline-editing).

How would I go about introducing that feature?

Answer (score 1):

For SugarCRM use following code:

```
$dictionary['module']['fields']['yourfield_c']['inlineedit']=false;
```

OR use **dependencies**

For SuiteCRM use following code:

```
$dictionary['module']['fields']['yourfield_c']['inline_edit']=false;
```

Comment: For SugarCRM, this method of turning off inline editing doesn't work. According to Sugar Support, inline editing cannot be turned off in versions up to 8.1. A feature request does exist to enable turning it off.